# When to use Sqoop --create-hive-table

Tags: hive, sqoop

Can anyone tell the difference between `create-hive-table`  & `hive-import` method? Both will create a hive table, but still what is the significance of each?

Answer (score 9):

**hive-import command:**
`hive-import` commands automatically populates the metadata for the populating tables in hive metastore. If the table in Hive does not exist yet, Sqoop
will simply create it based on the metadata fetched for your table or query. If the table already exists, Sqoop will import data into the existing table. If you’re creating a new Hive table, Sqoop will convert the data types of each column from your source table to a type compatible with Hive.
**create-hive-table command:**
Sqoop can generate a hive table (using `create-hive-table`command) based on the table from an existing relational data source. If set, then the job will fail if the target hive table exists. By default this property is false.
Using `create-hive-table` command involves **three** steps: importing data into HDFS, creating hive table and then loading the HDFS data into Hive. This can be shortened to one step by using `hive-import`. 
During a `hive-import`, Sqoop will first do a normal HDFS import to a temporary location. After a successful import, Sqoop generates two queries: one for creating a table and another one for loading the data from a temporary location. You can specify any temporary location using either the `--target-dir` or `--warehouse-dir` parameter.

**Added a example below for above description**

**Using create-hive-table command:**
Involves three steps:

1. Importing data from RDBMS to HDFS

   `sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hadoopexample --table employees --split-by empid -m 1;`
2. Creating hive table using `create-hive-table` command

   `sqoop create-hive-table --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hadoopexample --table employees --fields-terminated-by ',';`
3. Loading data into Hive

   `hive> load data inpath "employees" into table employees;
   Loading data to table default.employees
   Table default.employees stats: [numFiles=1, totalSize=70]
   OK
   Time taken: 2.269 seconds
   hive> select * from employees;
   OK
   1001    emp1    101
   1002    emp2    102
   1003    emp3    101
   1004    emp4    101
   1005    emp5    103
   Time taken: 0.334 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)`

**Using hive-import command:**

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hadoopexample --table departments --split-by deptid -m 1 --hive-import;`

Comment: I think that this copy & paste from user guide is not particularly helpful.

Comment: But when I tried using this command more than one time, I did'nt get error like table already exists..this is the commnad I tried..                                                                sqoop create-hive-table --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDB -username root -password root --table tb2; ..Can you please explain what do you mean by "create-hive-table command involves three steps" ..Can you please give me sample commands in this?? Thanks again :)

Comment: Please tell me what is the difference between the below 2 commands  sqoop-import  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1 -username root -password password --table tableName  --hive-table tableName --create-hive-table --hive-import

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that create-hive-table will create table in Hive based on the source table in database but will *NOT* transfer any data. Command "import --hive-import" will both create table in Hive and import data from the source table.

Comment: Does this create an internal or external table?