# Sqoop Import from MySql DB doesnt create Hive Table

Tags: import, sqoop

I tried many ways to create hive table by Sqoop import and none of these create a table in Hive side.
Any idea why this is happening. I can see the HDFS file /user/hive/warehouse/mysqldb.db/employees created and I can read the file content ,but i am unable to see the hive table at all

Any idea what is happening here

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MySQLDB --username userid --password xxxxx --split-by EMPLOYEE_ID –-hive-overwrite --e "select * from employees where EMPLOYEE_ID <=105 and $CONDITIONS"   --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/mysqldb.db/employees --fields-terminated-by ","  --hive-import --create-hive-table   --hive-table mysqldb.employees  --fields-terminated-by ","  -m2

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MySQLDB --username userid --password xxxxx --split-by EMPLOYEE_ID --table employees --hive-import -hive-overwrite -m 2

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515498/when-to-use-sqoop-create-hive-table

Comment: remove --hive-import from your first step and try.